# searching and deleting in activerecord array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Groups has_ many users. 
I have 2 activerecord arrays: 
1. groups = containing groups with its users. 
2. users = containing users attending an event.

I start by iterating over the groups. Then I iterate over the users in 
the second array and search for that user in the first array  (see 
code). If the user is found, show and delete from the array.

```
<% groups.each do |group| %> 
<h2><%= group.title %></h2> 
  <% users.each do |user| %> 
    # I want to search for user in group.users 
    # and if present show here and remove the user from 
    # group.users (remove from the array not from the database) 
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

I don't know how to search for a user in another active record array and 
then delete him. 
All help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Directly answering your question**, i.e. displaying *and deleting* a user of interest from all froups' users:

```
<% @groups.collect { |group|
     group.users.delete_if { |user|
       user == my_user
     }
   }.flatten.each do |user| %>

   <%= ((display user)) %>

<% end %>
```

Alternatively,

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
   <% if user = group.delete(my_user) %>
     <%= ((display user)) %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```